# jQuery Tools Scrollable Destroy and Re-init

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools, scrollable

Yep, there's a ton of questions on adding/removing items from scrollable. But, has anyone actually narrowed down the best way to unbind and destroy scrollable and then re-initialize it via a function? I have a certain amount of data, that once received and injected, inits scrollable. Then, via a drop-down, whichever option is selected, the area receives new data, so I'm trying to figure out how to destroy and remove all bindings (including navigator) and then re-init scrollable to accommodate the new data... Is there a hidden function via the api somewhere?